# Jmeter Duration time does not get reflected in Azure Load Testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, azure-load-testing

I am trying to execute my JMeter script via Azure Load Testing, I have setup a duration time in the JMeter script but when I execute via Azure Load Testing ,it does not get reflected, I cant figure from where the time is getting set. I am not sure how to configure that or where it gets overridden. Any support is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you provided `duration_in_sec` in your [Azure Load Test Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/quickstart-create-and-run-load-test#modify-load-test-parameters) - it will override whatever you have in the [.jmx test script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)

If you didn't - the duration will be taken from the [Thread Group(s)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

If you haven't specified duration in the Thread Group - the test will end as soon as the last thread (virtual user) executes last iteration of the last [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in the last Thread Group.

Otherwise you test will run forever.

More information: [JMeter Tutorial: Getting Started With the Basics](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-tutorial)